# The value of $\max_{i,j}\frac{a_{ij}}{b_{ij}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization

Assume $a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{21}+a_{22}=1$ and $b_{11}+b_{12}+b_{21}+b_{22}=1$, where all $a_{ij}, b_{ij}\ge 0$. Let $\frac{a_{i1}+a_{i2}}{b_{i1}+b_{i2}}\le \eta$ for all $i$ and let $\frac{a_{1j}+a_{2j}}{b_{1j}+b_{2j}}\le \eta$ for all $j$. My question: What is the value of $$\max_{i,j}\frac{a_{ij}}{b_{ij}}?$$

Comment: there seems to be a problem in your subscript for the ratios $\leq \eta$.

Comment: Is it $$\frac{a_{(i1+a_{i2})}}{b_{i1}+b_{i2}}$$ or $$\frac{a_{i1}+a_{i2}}{b_{i1}+b_{i2}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no maximum (i.e. it is unbounded).   It is easy to see $\eta \ge 1$.  Now consider $a_{jj}=b_{i\ne j} =\frac12$, and $a_{i\ne j} = b_{jj}=0$...

Comment: Thank you very much! Your counterexample prevent me to  waste more time to the wrong problem.

Comment: Glad to help...